# PostgreSQL- Restricting postgresql user access to a particular database

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have multiple databases in postgreSQL. I have created unique users with the intention of giving them access to a unique database. After creating the users, the first thing I did was use the following command:

> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE dbname to username;

Then all the created users could connect to all the existing databases.
After this I tried with a new user without granting any permissions. Instead I created a new role with connect on privilege to a particular database and attached this role to the new user. But the result was same, the new user could connect to any database. I then tried revoking all privileges with the command:

> REVOKE ALL ON DATABASE dbname FROM PUBLIC;

The issue remains.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Restrict user privileges to one particular database only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11012441/restrict-user-privileges-to-one-particular-database-only)

Answer (score 1):

Look at the permissions on the database:

```
SELECT datacl FROM pg_database WHERE datname = 'dbname';
```

If that is NULL, then the default permissions apply: the owner of the database has all privileges, and `PUBLIC` can `CONNECT` and `TEMP`.

In that case, your `REVOKE` statement would prevent `username` from connecting to that database, unless `username` is the owner of the database (or a member of the owner).

Comment: This didn't seem to solve the issue.

Comment: I used some "if"s in my answer. I can give you a more direct answer if you edit your question and show the result of the query in my answer.

Comment: how can we deny `PUBLIC` to connect ie only the permitted user can connect

Comment: @Hritik The `REVOKE` statement is in the question. With `GRANT` you can grant a user the privilege. You can also use `pg_hba.conf` for a similar purpose.